# Celery Task with countdown

Tags: python, celery

I am using Celery 2.5.1 and I am trying to use `countdown` to run the task after 20 seconds, but it gets executed immediately.

I am using it as:

```
DemoTask.apply_async(countdown = 20)
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Do you by any chance have `CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER = True`?

Comment: No I am not. I also tried setting `CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER = False`

Comment: @Siddharth does countdown not work with `CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER=True`? You would intuitively expect the same behaviour whether running synchronously or asynchronously, but it seems like countdown is ignored :/ I can't find any documentation stating this and reading the code doesn't seem obvious.

Comment: @MichaelAquilina just to be clear, it ignores the countdown?

Answer (score 17):

The problem is likely not being in the right timezone. By setting `countdown=20` you might be telling Celery to execute the task 20 seconds after 3 hours ago.

I suggest using the [pytz library](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/) to tell Celery to start the task at the right time:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from pytz import timezone

# Set timezone: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name
my_tz = timezone('US/Eastern')

DemoTask.apply_async(eta=my_tz.localize(datetime.now()) + timedelta(seconds=20))
```

Or even easier if you are using Django (and have set `TIME_ZONE` in `settings.py`):

```
from datetime import timedelta
from django.utils.timezone import now

DemoTask.apply_async(eta=now() + timedelta(seconds=20))
```

Comment: Had a similar issue. Summer savings time ended and all of a sudden our countdowns were ignored...

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. Commenting to verify this worked.

Comment: Does this only occur if your Celery worker server (or container or whatever) has a different default timezone to the server from which tasks are scheduled, because times on the queue are timezone naive?

Answer (score 6):

In addition for [the timezone problem laid out by @Banana](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24616628/35070), make sure that [the celery configuration option `always_eager`](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#std:setting-task_always_eager), which makes celery skip is set to `False` - otherwise, Celery ignores the countdown *and* the eta.